# Link View Product button to that page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to link the view button to their represented page.
[image]

The image shown is the product page.
When the user clicks on the view product it should send them to that product page.

The led plastic tube light for example should be send to that product page.
JS code for it:

```
{
  productName: "LED Plactice Tube Light",
  category: "LEDLightsIndoor",      
  image: "/img/glass-plastic-tubelight.jpg",
  info:"Available in Warm, Pure & Natural White.",
  info2:"Used in offices, retail stores, boardrooms, hotels, homes, banks, restaurants 
  and many more.",
  info3:"Saves up to 90% electricity.",
  button: "View Product",
},
```

To display the data:

```
for (let i of products.data) {

  //Create Card
  let card = document.createElement("div");
  //Card should have category and should stay hidden initially
  card.classList.add("card", i.category, "hide");
  //image div
  let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
  imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
  //img tag
  let image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
  imgContainer.appendChild(image);
  card.appendChild(imgContainer);
  //container
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  container.classList.add("container");
  //product name
  let name = document.createElement("h5");
  name.classList.add("product-name");
  name.innerText = i.productName.toUpperCase();
  container.appendChild(name);
  //info
  let info = document.createElement("div");
  info.classList.add("info");
  info.innerText = i.info.toUpperCase();
  container.appendChild(info);

  let info2 = document.createElement("div");
  info2.classList.add("info");
  info2.innerText = i.info2.toUpperCase();
  container.appendChild(info2);

  let info3 = document.createElement("div");
  info3.classList.add("info");
  info3.innerText = i.info3.toUpperCase();
  container.appendChild(info3);

  //view product button
  let button = document.createElement("div");
  button.classList.add("glow-on-hover");
  button.innerText = i.button.toUpperCase();
  container.appendChild(button);



  card.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
}
```

How do I create the link for it then?

Comment: if you were using anchors, it would be as easy as setting the `href` attribute of the element you are creating. Since you are using buttons, you should attach a click event handler where you will be moving the location (window.location.assign). Anyway in your object you don't have the coordinates of the product landing page